# Is it possible to add runtime parameters based on condition - Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

My current azure pipeline looks like following -

```
parameters:
  - name: Deploy
    type: Boolean
    default: false
  - name: Stages
    type: string
    values:
       - Stg A
       - Stg B
       - Stg C
       - Stg D
       - Stg E
```

I was trying to add a condition in such a way that if user checks `Deploy` on running pipeline, it should dynamically show up only `Stg A`, `Stg B` as values for `Stages`. And if they uncheck `Deploy`, it should show `Stg C`, `Stg D` and `Stg E`.

I tried to add conditions in following way -

```
 parameters:
  - name: Deploy
    type: Boolean
    default: false
  - name: Stages
    type: string
    ${{ if eq(parameters['Deploy'], 'true' ) }}:
     values: 
       - Stg A
       - Stg B
    ${{ if ne(parameters['Deploy'], 'true' ) }}:
     values:
       - Stg C
       - Stg D
       - Stg E
```

However, the following conditional way worked for `variables`, but did not work for `parameters`. Is there any way to achieve this in Azure pipelines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible to add runtime parameters based on condition - Azure Devops Pipeline

I am afraid it it impossible to runtime parameters conditionally define values based on another parameter value.

Because the parameters need to be defined before the pipeline run starts. As stated in the document [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)：

> Parameters are only available at template parsing time. **Parameters are
> expanded just before the pipeline runs** so that values surrounded
> by ${{ }} are replaced with parameter values. Use variables if you
> need your values to be more widely available during your pipeline run.

As workaround, we could use condition in the steps:

```
 parameters:
  - name: Deploy
    type: Boolean
    default: false

stages:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters['Deploy'], 'true' ) }}:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        stages:
          - "Stg A"
          - "Stg B"
  - ${{ if ne(parameters['Deploy'], 'true' ) }}:
    - template: template.yml 
      parameters:
        stages:
          - "Stg C"
          - "Stg D"
          - "Stg E"
```

Comment: Please check my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

No. However, you can pass parameters with conditional template as below.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: Deploy
    type: Boolean
    default: false

stages:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
        ${{ if eq(parameters['Deploy'], 'true' ) }}:
          stages:
            - "Stg A"
            - "Stg B"
        ${{ else }}:
          stages:
            - "Stg C"
            - "Stg D"
            - "Stg E"
```