# Unable to pass list to Azure task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, devops

I am creating CI/CD pipeline for Azure SQL Database where pipeline should execute only updated scripts. To achieve this, I used below code:

trigger:
branches:
include:
- refs/heads/develop
exclude:
- /Scripts/Camilion/Landing/Drop
- /Scripts/Portal/Staging/Drop

resources:
repositories:

- repository: self
  type: git
  ref: refs/heads/develop

pool:
vmImage: windows-latest

stages:

- stage: 'SSISPackage'
  jobs:

  - job: SSISJob
    steps:

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Check Updated Files'
      inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script:
      echo "****Updated Projects***"
      git diff --name-only $(git merge-base origin/workitems/sp-004-ust-dummy HEAD)| sed '/yml$/d'|cut -d '/' -f2

I am getting expected output,

****Updated Projects***
StarrDataMigration
Camilion
Portal

Issue:
I want run azure task for each value in the output. Tried to assign the output to an array variable and pass to task but it didn’t work. Any idea how can I achieve my requirement.
Thanks in Advance..!

I tried to assign the output to an array variable and pass across azure tasks but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can redirect your output to some text file:

```
task: Bash@3 
  displayName: 'Check Updated Files' 
  inputs: 
    targetType: 'inline' 
    script: 
      git diff --name-only $(git merge-base origin/workitems/sp-004-ust-dummy HEAD)| sed '/yml$/d'|cut -d '/' -f2 >> some_text.txt
```

Then read and parse it.... as an example on Powershell:

```
$result = Get-Content "some_text.txt"

$resArray = $result.Split(" ")

foreach ($resValue in $resArray)
{
    run_your_cmd_here $resValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is, I want to repeat set of azure tasks or a template for each value in that file. How can I achieve that. I tried by setting task variable and pass to another task but it doesn't work. Tried below commands,
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetfiles]$result"
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetfiles]$result[]"

Comment: @VinodKumar, yaml does not support arrays https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def/812728 . This example `write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetfiles]$result"` should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#examples-1

Comment: Tried below code,
jobs:
    - job: statusJob
      steps:

      - task: PowerShell@1
        inputs:
          scriptType: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
              git diff --name-only $(git merge-base origin/main HEAD) >> filelists
              $result = Get-Content "filelists"
              write-host $result
              write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetfiles]$result"

Comment: - job: buildJob
      displayName: Build Job
      dependsOn: ['statusJob']
      variables: 
        someName: $[ dependencies.statusJob.outputs['setVariable.targetfiles'] ]
      steps: 
      - {{ each value in someName}}
        - task: PowerShell@1
          inputs:
            scriptType: inlineScript
            inlineScript: |
              write-host $(someName)

Comment: @VinodKumar Azure DevOps pipelines do not support arrays. Check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67184922/is-it-possible-to-add-runtime-parameters-based-on-condition-azure-devops-pipel and https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/188

Comment: @VinodKumar As a workaround, you can use two separate pipelines: 1 - read vars, 2 - run build. The first read your variables and queue your second build with REST API per each variable..

Comment: Hi,
How can I pass variables from one pipeline to another. Any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the previous answer. You can parse your resulting file and run the second pipeline with the following example:

```
$token = "$(System.AccessToken)" 

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
$teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"

$buildDefId = 'TARGET_BUILD_ID'

$restRunBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7"

function InvokePostRequest ($PostUrl, $BuildBody)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $BuildBody -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}

$buildbody = @"
{
"parameters":  "{\"my.var1\":  \"MY_VAR1\", \"my.var2\":  \"MY_VAR2\"}",
"definition":   {"id":  DEF_ID}
}
"@

$buildbody = $buildbody.Replace("DEF_ID", $buildDefId);
$buildbody = $buildbody.Replace("MY_VAR1", "value 1");
$buildbody = $buildbody.Replace("MY_VAR2", "value 2");

$result = InvokePostRequest $restRunBuild $buildbody

$result
```